# Best Strategy to combine Facebook and Local Registration in Passport

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, passport.js

I have an app with both fb logins and local logins implemented. Now I'm trying to figure out the best way to combine these strategies. As I see it, I can either

- maintain two records
- combine the two records

Taking the first option would mean two scenarios: FB record first, or Local registration first. If FB precedes a local registration, I would need to add a hashed password to a record containing an FB ID and email (I'm using email as the primary identifier in the local login as well). That seems like the bigger challenge. But perhaps that's not a great idea - I'm trying to find out what strategies are best supported and practically workable.

For the moment, I'm using just these two strategies, but the app I'm building will probably want to add other social media strategies, which seems to favour allowing each login type to be a separate record.

Can anyone suggest a best-practice, and perhaps help me out with adding a password to a record that represents a previous FB login?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, there are many ways to solve this. You will have to pick the one that suits your needs best.

To give an example : if you look at parse apps, they support FB login, Twitter login and local registration. They manage this by creating a user record and then storing access tokens for the FB / Twitter logins along with emails & password (used in local registrations).

in your case, it would creating FB/Twitter/other services records against local logins. Does that make sense?

Check out the parse FB integration and see how things work. It should give you a great idea.